# Compound beta-binomial and beta distribution

Tags: beta-distribution, conjugate-prior, beta-binomial-distribution, compound-distributions

I have a process that is modelled by a beta-binomial, parametrised by mean $\mu$ and correlation $\rho = 1/(\alpha+\beta+1)$ (as per dbetabinom in the R VGAM package).  I know $\rho$, but the mean $\mu$ is itself given by a beta distribution with parameters $a$ and $b$.

I would like to marginalise over the beta distribution on $\mu$.  If the likelihood was given by a binomial distribution, I know the result would be a beta-binomial.  Is there an equivalent closed form solution for the compound distribution of a beta-binomial and beta distribution?